# Firebase UI Phone Authentication not working on angular 13 using @angular/fire for firebase web modular v9

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, angularfire, firebaseui

I'm using angular v13 and firebaseui and @angular/fire for authentication base on firebase V9 web modular ,
all sign in methods authentication providers are working except the phone authentication I got error type  in console and even RecaptchaVerifier not showed and I got message error "Solve the reCAPTCHA"

> ERROR TypeError: app.auth is not a function
> at new RecaptchaVerifier (index.esm2017.js:931:13)
> at K.phoneSignInStart (esm.js:339:310)

app.module.ts

```
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth())
  ]
```

```
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'
import {Auth, PhoneAuthProvider
} from '@angular/fire/auth'

constructor(private auth:Auth){
    const ui=new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(this.auth)
    ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
      signInOptions: [
        {provider:PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          recaptchaParameters: {
            type: 'image',
            size: 'normal',
            badge: 'bottomleft' 
          }
        }              
      ]
     })
```

I require the official way using official firebaseui

Answer (score 3):

Using the Firebase Authentication SDK it works

```js
import {Auth,RecaptchaVerifier,signInWithPhoneNumber,PhoneAuthProvider,signInWithCredential} from '@angular/fire/auth'
import {FormGroup,FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {Subject, tap} from 'rxjs';
```

```js
constructor(private auth: Auth) { }
  phoneNumber$=new Subject<string>();
  code$=new Subject<string>();
  phoneNumberForm=new FormGroup({phoneNumberInput:new FormControl('')})
  verifyForm=new FormGroup({codeInput:new FormControl('')})
  displayPhoneDiv=true;
  displayCodeDiv=false;
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    let appVerifier= new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
      'size':'invisible', //'normal'
      'callback': (response:any) => {},
      'expired-callback': () => {}
    }, this.auth)

    this.phoneNumber$.pipe(
      tap((phoneNumber:string) =>{
        this.displayPhoneDiv=false;
        signInWithPhoneNumber(this.auth,phoneNumber,appVerifier)
          .then((confirmationResult) => {          
          this.displayCodeDiv=true
          this.code$.pipe(
            tap((code) => {
              console.log(confirmationResult)
              var credential =PhoneAuthProvider.credential(confirmationResult.verificationId,code)
              signInWithCredential(this.auth,credential)
              .then((result) => {
                this.displayCodeDiv=false
                console.log(result)
              })
            })).subscribe()
          })
      })
    ).subscribe()         
  }

  getPhoneNumber(){
    this.phoneNumber$.next(this.phoneNumberForm.controls['phoneNumberInput'].value)
  }
  getCode(){
    this.code$.next(this.verifyForm.controls['codeInput'].value)
  }
```

```html
<div *ngIf="displayPhoneDiv">
    <h2>Phone Number</h2>
    <form [formGroup]="phoneNumberForm" (ngSubmit)="getPhoneNumber()">
      <input 
      formControlName="phoneNumberInput">
      <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </form>  
  </div>
  
  <div *ngIf="displayCodeDiv">
    <h2>Verify code</h2>
      <form [formGroup]="verifyForm" (ngSubmit)="getCode()">
        <input 
        formControlName="codeInput">
        <button type="submit">Verify Code</button>
    </form>  
    </div>
  
  <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
```

Comment: Answered using, Firebase Authentication SDK, Any one can help to answer using Firebase UI ??